# Java SocketChannel closed on other thread

Tags: java, multithreading, socketchannel

I have a thread, witch is testing a socketchannel selector.
If a socketchannel is connected, and can be read, it should start a message handler thread, where the message is read, and handled.
I need to start the handler thread, because there have a lot to do, and it needs time to finish them.

main thread:

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Wait for an event one of the registered channels
            this.selector.select();

            // Iterate over the set of keys for which events are available
            Iterator selectedKeys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) selectedKeys.next();
                selectedKeys.remove();

                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check what event is available and deal with it
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.accept(key);
                }
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    this.read(key);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

read function:

```
    private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        // For an accept to be pending the channel must be a server socket channel.
        SocketChannel clientSocketChanel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        WebCommandHandler commands = new WebCommandHandler(clientSocketChanel);
        if (clientSocketChanel.isConnected()) {
            Thread cThread = new Thread(commands);
            cThread.setName("Message handler");
            cThread.start();
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when the handler thread is executed, the given socketchannel is already closed. 
If i don't run the thread, only i'm calling the run() method, then the socket isn't closing, so I think the main thread iteration is closing the given SocketChannel. Can somebody help me figuring out a workaround, how can i keep the SocketChannel opened, until the handler thread stops working?

**EDIT**

Probably i should "unregister" the SocketChannel from the selector, before starting the new thread... How can i unregister a socketChannel from a Seelctor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have found the solution...
So, we should de-register the SocketChannel from the Selector... And this can be achived by calling the key.cancel() function.